# What is elasticsearch watcher actions logging index name?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk, elasticsearch-watcher

I created a new watcher definition. It works successfully.

I cannot find the logs written in Actions logging.
In which index name are these log records stored?

```
"actions": {
    "my-logging-action": {
        "logging": {
            "level": "warn",
            "text": "my-logging-action There has been no {{ctx.metadata.title}} request in the last {{ctx.metadata.interval_text}}."
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be under .watches index.

Here it is mentioned:
[elastic.co](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/watcher-api-put-watch.html)

The indices which begin with a dot are hidden indices. They can be found under:

**Kibana -> Stack Management -> Indices -> Include hidden indices (Top slide bar)**